# Combining Angular (5.2) router with angular-ui-router (angular 1.3.19)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular, router

I'm building an app that should run inside of an AngularJS (1.3.19) module.
The motivation is to reuse AngularJS' already built services and controllers by the `scope()` and `injector()` functions.

**I cannot use ng-upgrade because this will require refactoring a lot of our legacy code.**

Is there a way I can combine two routers for two different AngularJS modules?
We use  the `angular-ui-router` for our AngularJS app.
When I try to change a route on the Angular router, AngularJS' router removes the route and replaces it with an empty string (and runs the `otherwise()` function as configured).

Any ideas?
Thanks!

Comment: Such a complicated situation! You should not use Angularjs with Angular. That sounds not correct, anyway, the Angular router is much easier and more flexiable. Change your routes and use Angular router

Comment: what would motivate you to wrap an angular application in an angularjs one? Why not implementing the wrapped app in angularjs too? Im curious

Comment: We still want to use new technology with its added features (better change detection, rendering, component based) while keeping our services and controllers (scopes) from the old framework.
We're still testing this integration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got this.
Configure your paths on both ends. AngularJS' route should point at the html of your Angular app.
Also, I created a node script that imports Angular's routes and transforms them to be AngularJS' routes.
I did this with **ts-node** and **webpack-shell-plugin**.

Thanks.